# Can't get state to update in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update a state with products that are being fetched from Contentful, but they aren't updating right away.

I'm calling getProducts() inside useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getProducts(products, setProducts);
  }, []);
```

And in my getProducts() function, I'm fetching the data from Contentful, setting it to a state (products) and later saving this same state to localStorage.

```
export async function getProducts(products, setProducts) {
  try {
    let contentful = await client.getEntries("products");

    setProducts(contentful.items);
    saveProducts(products);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

The problem is that, when I save it to localStorage, I get an empty array.

I don't know if I'm using useEffect wrong or something, but I'd be glad if anyone could help me out.

Comment: setting state in React, whether via `this.setState` in a class or via hooks, is asynchronous - it doesn't take place immediately. This should be obvious with hooks - calling a function `setProducts` can't possibly immediately change the value of a separate variable called `products`. It just means that, on a later render, `products` will have the value you pass.

Comment: The array at the end of `useEffect` is a list of dependencies of the `useEffect`. The `useEffect` is run once on component mount and for each time one of the dependencies changes (shallow compare). With what you have at the moment the `useEffect` will only run once on component mount. I would suggest removing `products` from your `getProducts` function and passing `contentful.items` directly to `saveProducts`.